# finding the set of all points in the plane satisfying a certain equation

Tags: calculus

want to find and draw the set of all $(x,y)$ such that $f(x,y)=c$.

1. $f(x,y)=min\{x+y,x^2-y\} , c=1$
2. $f(x,y)=max\{x+y,x^2-y\} , c=1$
3. $f(x,y)=y-x-2$ if $x\leq0$ and
   $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{2}y-x^2$ if $x>0$
   $c=0, 3$

So, in 1 and 2, we should look at two cases right?
For example in 2:
When
$x+y<x^2-y--> f(x,y)=x^2-y=1$
And
$x+y>x^2-y-->
 f(x,y)=x+y=1$

For 3, do we need to look at each interval and solve f(x,y)=c?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $$2\min(A,B)=A+B-\lvert A-B\rvert$$ So for case (1), you want the solution set to

$$\begin{align}
2&=(x+y)+\left(x^2-y\right)-\left\lvert(x+y)-\left(x^2-y\right)\right\rvert\\
2&=x+x^2-\left\lvert 2y+x-x^2\right\rvert\\
\left\lvert 2y+x-x^2\right\rvert&=x^2+x-2=(x+2)(x-1)
\end{align}$$
The right side is negative for $x\in(-2,1)$ so nothing you draw will be in that strip.

For $x\in(-\infty,-2]\cup[1,\infty)$:
$$\begin{align}
\left\lvert 2y+x-x^2\right\rvert&=x^2+x-2\\
2y+x-x^2&=\pm(x^2+x-2)\\
\end{align}$$

So either $y=x^2-1$ or $y=-x+1$. Draw these two curves for $x\in(-\infty,-2]\cup[1,\infty)$.

[image]

You should be able to adapt this for (2).

(3) seems trivial. I would not say "for each interval", but rather "for each half-plane".

Comment: Thanks @2'5 9'2 in 2, I got $y=-x-1$ or $y=x^2+1$ for $x\in (-2,1)$, and in 3 for $c=0$ it is $y=x+2$ if $x\leq 0$ and $y=2x^2$ if $x>0$, does it look fine?

Comment: I haven't checked your answers but they seem plausible. Your case (3) had two values for $c$ though, not just $c=0$.